# determines the number of daily active users per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample data:

```
ID  time    user_id event
1   2021-11-11  15  access benifits
2   2021-12-25  6   submit policy
3   2022-01-02  9   submit policy
4   2021-12-01  13  create payslip
5   2021-11-24  15  create payslip
6   2021-11-25  15  create payslip
7   2022-01-03  7   create payslip
8   2021-12-22  9   access benifits
9   2021-11-08  2   submit policy
10  2022-01-15  5   submit policy
11  2021-11-17  9   access benifits
12  2022-01-12  11  create payslip
13  2021-12-27  1   submit policy
14  2021-11-10  4   submit policy
15  2022-01-24  2   create payslip
```

I want determines the number of daily active users per month.

I tried it Like

```
SELECT  user_id, MONTHNAME(time) mon , COUNT(*) cnt FROM ACTIVITIES 
GROUP by user_id, MONTH(time) HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This gives me accurate result for each user and each month.

result of my query.

```
user_id mon cnt
1   December    1
2   January 1
2   November    1
4   November    1
5   January 1
6   December    1
7   January 1
9   January 1
9   November    1
9   December    1
11  January 1
13  December    1
```

**I want to count distinct user_id from this query result.**

I am using MySQL.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) what results look like for your sample data.  you will get better help if your sample data is in text, too

Comment: Hi please check it now

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want e.g. 2021-01-24 and 2022-01-01 both totalled in "January", since they are different years?  or are you filtering on a date range?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put your query (without the HAVING, I'm not sure what the point of that was) in a subquery and total it:

```
select mon, count(*) active_users
from (
    SELECT  user_id, MONTHNAME(time) mon , COUNT(*) cnt FROM ACTIVITIES 
    GROUP by user_id, MONTH(time)
)
group by mon
```